# Como eu faço o layout de um app android no Photoshop usando PX se a google só me fornece DP?

Tags: android, android-layout, photoshop

Estou tentando desenhar o layout no photoshop, mas não consigo entender essa história de DP no photoshop, no código tudo bem, o compilador entende, mas no photoshop só posso trabalhar em PX.

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa? Tipo, a altura da status bar ou a action bar, a distância dos elementos e etc.

Comment: Veja se isso lhe ajuda 
http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/

a distancia dos elementos você pode usar a propriedade margin/padding deles dependendo que queira fazer.

Comment: Ajuda sim @Paulo obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer a conversão de pixel pra dp dependendo da densidade da tela que você pretende desenvolver, relação pixel dp é dada por:

pixel / densidade

Por exemplo, caso você queira desenvolver para a densidade hdpi o valor da densidade é 2.0x, se você tiver uma imagem de 500p de largura o equivalente em dp é dado por:

500 / 2.0 = 250dp

É claro que dependendo do layout esse valor pode ser adaptado, caso o resultado dê um valor fracionario e etc.

Recomendo a leitura dessa [página](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Isso deve te ajudar a entender melhor as densidades do Android.